# Adding dedicate circuit to old panel

Tags: electrical-panel, heater, remodeling, old-house

I want to add a dedicated circuit for a wall heater in the bathroom. Attached is a picture of my power panel. How do I tell if I have enough room to add to my existing panel? Housing is currently knob and tube. [image]

Comment: How many amps does this new wall heater draw?

Comment: Also, how many square feet is the house, how many amps does the mini-split pull, and I take it the ? labels in your new photo from your other question mean that you haven't been able to ID the circuit yet?